# Finding the constant $\theta_0$ in the orbit equation for motion in $\vec F=\frac{K}{r^2}\hat{r}$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

Solving the equation of orbit for a particle of mass $m$ moving under an inverse-square force $\vec F=\frac{K}{r^2}\hat{r}$ is given by $$u=\frac{1}{r}=-\frac{mK}{L^2}+C\cos(\theta-\theta_0)$$ where $L$ is the magnitude of the angular momentum about the center of the force and $C,\theta_0$ are two unknown constants to be determined. The quantity $C$ can be found using the conservation of energy. Now it is possible to choose a coordinate system such that $\theta_0=0$. But suppose we don't do that. In that case, does anyone have any idea how to find the constant $\theta_0$?

Answer (score 2):

You need to know the (conserved) value of the Runge-Lenz vector $\textbf p\times\textbf L-mK\hat{\textbf r}$. This points in the direction from the centre of force towards the periapsis, which is your $\theta_0$. The vector lies in the plane of the orbit, as you can see from its definition, and its magnitude gives you an alternative route to the constant $C$. Check out Hamilton's solution for this problem - staggeringly elegant!